# Twig C extension on debian servers with package php5-twig and twig from composer, will it work?

Tags: debian, twig, composer-php, php-extension, twig-extension

I am using Twig (composer version) on a shared Debian (stable) web server where only deb packages can be installed.

- Should I ask the administrator to install the Debian C extension for Twig?
- The version of Twig (php library) from composer will be more recent than the one from the C extension from Debian: what result will it give?

  - Twig may fail in some circonstances.
  - Twig will see the extension is from an older version and ignore it.
  - If it is just a little older, Twig can use the C extension.
- Today debian stable version is 1.16.2 and composer version is 1.24.0

I have a choice:

1. use Twig from composer 100% php, version 1.24.0, without C extension
2. use Twig from composer php version 1.24.0, with C extension from Debian, version 1.16.2 (but will it work?)
3. use Twig php and C extension from Debian, version 1.16.2 The extension will work, but I don't know yet how to configure composer for this, because I need composer for other php packages, not in Debian and depending from Twig.)

My question is what is the best choice? I could make a test and profile it, but I don't know yet how to write a simple code to show the gain of using Twig C extension.

References:

- https://packagist.org/packages/twig/twig
- https://packages.debian.org/en/stable/php5-twig
- twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/installation.html
- stackoverflow.com/questions/20400777/how-to-speed-up-template-rendering-in-symfony2

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Why don't you give it a try?

Comment: @StephanVierkant I tried to improve my question. I didn't test because I am not sure how to write a simple Twig template to show the gain with the C extension.

Comment: Why don't your benchmark your real app? Maybe your simple test isn't representative. That makes your test useless because it doesn't measure the real gain. My suggestion: don't waste your time on an extension, but try to upgrade to PHP 7 if you care about performance.